# Why did Regan look worried when Beau signed to her about Rocket?

Tags: a-quiet-place

In Science fiction *A Quiet Place (2018)*, Regan checks on her younger brother, Beau, who is drawing a picture of a rocket on the floor. He signs to Regan, "Rocket. That's how we'll get away." then she looked worried.

[image]

Why did she look worried when Beau signed to her about Rocket?

Comment: Seems like she felt bad because there was no chance of that happening, from what I recall.